# Did the Supreme Court have a time limit on responding to Texas v Pennsylvania et. al?

Tags: united-states, election, supreme-court, texas

In [the lawsuit](https://www.supremecourt.gov/docket/docketfiles/html/public/22o155.html) filed by Texas against Pennsylvania and other states, SCOTUS did request the defendants to respond by December 10, 2020, but they did not say until December 11 that they were not going to hear the case, or give any sort of indication of a ruling on the case until then.

Given that one of the things that the plaintiffs are asking for was a change in what happens on December 14, 2020, when the electoral college meets, was SCOTUS required to give some sort of response before then, even if that response was to say "we aren't going to take the case"? Or could SCOTUS have simply left the case there, untouched by them in any way, until past December 14?

And if they had done so, would they even have had an option to find for the plaintiffs at that point? Since the electoral college would have already met, it would be actually impossible to give Texas what they were asking for wouldn't it?

To sum up the primary question, **are there any rules that required SCOTUS to give some sort of response to this lawsuit before December 14?**

Comment: Generally, if remedy is no longer possible, the lawsuit is dismissed. (Search on law SE for more on this.) Note that the court may come up with an alternative remedy on its own, i.e. it's not bound to exactly what the plaintiffs asked for; see https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artIII_S2_C1_1_7_3_2/

Comment: Also, elections have been invalidated by federal judges even after a party had taken his seat. See Pennsylvania senate election 1993. I'm guessing SCOTUS would be much more weary of undoing a POTUS election in such a time-delayed manner, but I don't know if it would be outright unconstitutional for them to do so. (And who could decide if SCOTUS  did something unconstitutional? Presumably the only fix for that is to pack SCOTUS and get a new decision to overturn old one...)

Comment: @Fizz The Army? I'm mostly joking, but if the Supreme Court throws out the election and installs their choice of President, that would be a Constitutional Crisis, and, like any coup attempt, the outcome would come down to whether the people with the power to enforce an outcome (which is generally the people with the guns) accept or reject it.

Comment: *If* (and that's a big if) the case is granted certiorari, then Rule 27(1) says: "A case ordinarily will not be
called for argument less than two weeks after the brief on the merits for the respondent or appellee is due." But since the Court sets its own rules, they can of course change that.

Comment: That the Supreme Court just rejected the Texas lawsuit on the basis of lack of standing makes this question moot.

Comment: @Fizz This was an original jurisdiction case rather than a certiorari case. A subtle difference but Rule 27(1) does not apply to it.

Comment: We now know for certain that these states lack standing. https://www.cnn.com/2020/12/11/politics/supreme-court-order-texas-election-case/index.html

Comment: Updated the tense of the question so that it still works the same even though there is now news about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> are there any rules that require SCOTUS to give some sort of response
> to this lawsuit before December 14?

No. Best practices of the court are usually (but not always) to address petitions before they become moot. But there have been times in the currently election cycle when it had already deliberately not taken action until an election related petition is moot, and it has even done so in a handful of death penalty cases historically.

Also, even if there was, no one could enforce them because there is no court to which anyone can appeal from the U.S. Supreme Court.

Comment: Just to be clear: they don't have a deadline to respond and can just ignore or decline to rule on it, but they do still have a deadline to respond if they want to change the outcome, right?

Comment: @divibisan: given Bush v. Gore, they'd probably loathe to start some process unless the outcome was likely to be a quick one. But I think technically they could start a hearing that 2 years from now decides the election was fraudulent. It would be entirely unprecedented though. Keep in mind that original jurisdiction cases generally get referred to a "special master" court for the actual findings of fact, which is a fairly lengthy process. Wikipedia even [gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_master) 1948 as an example when that happened for election fraud claims but not via SCOTUS.

Comment: And from a much better [source](https://scholarship.law.umn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1845&context=mlr): "In New
Jersey v. New York, a contentious dispute dating back to the
early 1800s, a Special Master officiated over the full course of
proceedings for more than two years before formulating a 168-
page report, plus appendices, that set forth both his findings of
fact and his conclusions of law."

Comment: @divibisan Correct. At some point the matter becomes non-justiciable. In my opinion, that happens at the latest when Electoral College votes are cast and transmitted (December 14, 2020 this year). The court entertains the possibility that this point could be until Congress counts the Electoral College votes (this year on January 6, 2021) in *Bush v. Gore* but that portion of the opinion was dicta and is not a binding precedent because that issues wasn't presented in that case.